# ezjail: "partially completed upgrade"

Tags: freebsd, update, jail

I just updated FreeBSD to 10.2 and after trying to update my jails through ezjail I get the following :

```
ezjail-admin update -u

Looking up update.FreeBSD.org mirrors... 5 mirrors found.
Fetching metadata signature for 10.2-RELEASE from update4.freebsd.org... done.
Fetching metadata index... done.
Inspecting system... done.
Preparing to download files... done.

No updates needed to update system to 10.2-RELEASE-p7.
No updates are available to install.
Run '/usr/sbin/freebsd-update fetch' first.
You have a partially completed upgrade pending
Run '/usr/sbin/freebsd-update install' first.
Run '/usr/sbin/freebsd-update fetch -F' to proceed anyway.
```

I already tried `ezjail-admin install` but it didn't change the situation.

Inside the jails, `freebsd-version` shows `10.2-RELEASE-p7`

What am I missing?

Comment: First, do what it told you to do.

Comment: @MichaelHampton What did you tell me to do?

Comment: I told you to read the output that you pasted here without reading it, and follow the directions it gave you.

Comment: @MichaelHampton the commands don't do anything since it's not the base system that has the pending updates but the basejail…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution here:

https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/ezjail-warning-about-partial-upgrade.52030/#post-297471

> I just "fixed" this on my machine. The problem is that the newjail has
>   symlinks to /basejail, which doesn't exist on my system. I did:
>
> > ```
> > sudo mkdir /basejail; 
> > sudo mount -t nullfs /usr/jails/basejail /basejail/; 
> > sudo freebsd-update -b /usr/jails/newjail install; 
> > sudo ezjail-admin update -u
> > ```
>
> It worked from there.